# must be owner of type character varying or type uuid

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am researching clouds and have to compare them for our application. I got problem with GCP's "PostgreSQL 9.6"
During installation following CAST made:

```
CREATE CAST (character varying AS uuid) WITH FUNCTION varchar2uuid(IN pv character varying) AS IMPLICIT;
```

Works everywhere except GCP, postgresql has insufficient rights for it:

```
postgres=> CREATE CAST (character varying AS uuid) WITH FUNCTION varchar2uuid(IN pv character varying) AS IMPLICIT;
ERROR:  must be owner of type character varying or type uuid
```

As I understand, I shouldexecute "CREATE CAST" under superuser, but GCP does not allow it.
How to resolve problem? IS it possible to create cast without superuser?

Comment: Hey, have you figured out how to solve this?

Comment: I only found this

https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/unable-to-run-create-cast-command-in-postgresql-000004495

Answer (score -1):

`alter type uuid owner to your_user;`

Comment: it's not working from postgres user, since it's not a superuser.